# Highlighting Cells With Contents From Others

Tags: microsoft-excel

i would like to make cell A change to Red when there is contents in cell D

the contents in cell D will most likely never be typed the same

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what you want? At this point it's hard to understand what you really want. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Check out functions like sorry isnumber() (*isnum()*) or istext() and conditional formatting.

You don't explain what you are looking for letter, word, number so those tools may get you going.

Comment: what I'm looking to do would be some cells would have numbers and some could have 3-4 letters and some could have full words. I was using conditional formatting but wasn't coming up with a formula that was working for me. I'll give this a shot see what I come up with

Comment: Otherwise post a screenshot showing source and what you want to achieve then people can follow what you want.

Comment: hey everyone I did get it to work with istext() it is probably more complex than it needs to be being that i used an AND formula in conditional formatting =AND(U3=ISTEXT(U3))=FALSE which is changing the color of the selected cell once U3 has anything typed in it

Comment: Way to go, what works works, ain't a competition for the neatest shortest most elegant - get the job done !! But do come and see other answers if they happen : other techniques are always handy ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=D1<>""
```

If A1 is the first cell to Format

- Select the cells that you want to format
- Conditional Formatting
- New rule
- Use Formula to determine which cells to format
- Write the formula `=D1<>""`
- Format as you like